# How to convert string like "//u****" to text?

Tags: haskell, unicode

I want to convert a string like "//u****" to text (unicode) in Haskell.

I have a Java propertyes file, and it has the following content:

```
i18n.test.key=\u0050\u0069\u006e\u0067\u0020\uc190\uc2e4\ub960\u0020\ud50c\ub7ec\uadf8\uc778
```

I wanna convert it to text (Unicode) in Haskell.

I think I can do it like this:

1. Convert "\u****" to word8 array
2. Convert word8 array to ByteString
3. Use `Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8` convert ByteString to text

But step 1 is little complicated for me.

How to do it in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution may look like this:

```
decodeJava = T.decodeUtf16BE . BS.concat . gobble

gobble []                      = []
gobble ('\\':'u':a:b:c:d:rest) = let sym = convert16 [a,b] [c,d]
                                 in  sym : gobble rest
gobble _                       = error "decoding error"

convert16 hi lo = BS.pack [read $ "0x"++hi, read $ "0x"++lo]
```

**Notes:**

- Your string is UTF16-encoded, therefore you need `decodeUtf16BE`.
- Decoding will fail if there are other characters in the string. This code will work with your example only if you remove the trailing `i`.
- Constructing the words by appending `0x` and, in particular, using `read` is very slow, but will do the trick for small data.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `\u` with `\x` then this is a valid Haskell string literal.

```
my_string = "\x0050\x0069\x006e..."
```

You can then convert to `Text` if you want, or leave it as `String`, or whatever.

Comment: This is not fully correct. There are unicode characters that are represented in  2 Java chars. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, Java normally uses UTF-16 to encode its strings, so interpreting the bytes as UTF-8 will probably not work.

If the codes in your file are UTF-16, you need to do the following:

1. find the numeric value (Unicode code point) for each quadrupel
2. check if this is a high surrogate character. If this is so, the following character will be a low surrogate character. The pair of surrogate characters can be mapped to a Unicode point.
3. make a String from your list of unicode numbers with `map fromEnum`

The following is a quote from the Java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ :

> The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value. (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)
>
> The set of characters from U+0000 to U+FFFF is sometimes referred to as the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Characters whose code points are greater than U+FFFF are called supplementary characters. The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation, supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).

Java has methods to combine a high surrogate character and a low surrogate character to get the Unicode point. You may want to check the source of the `java.lang.Character` class to find out how exactly they do this, but I guess it is some simple bit-operation.

Another possibility would be to check for a Haskell library that does UTF-16 decoding.